# Join columns with specific match case

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `TableA` and `TableB`.
 
The `TableA` having column called `Code` Like

```
'A'
'AB'
'B'
'BB'
```

In `TableB` I have column called `pnrcode` like

```
'A001'
'AB001'
'B001'
'BC001'
```

Both tables have no relationship.
 
I want to join this two table based on `TableA` code with `TableB` pnrcode with matching the characters based on `TableA`

Comment: Can you show us what you have already treid to do this please

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Seems like a bit of a database design mistake that has got you into this situation! Is it possible to re-design these tables rather than invent complex queries to get around the error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySql 8.* you can use REGEXP_SUBSTR in a subquery to join the two tables

```
SELECT a.*, b.prncode 
FROM TableA a
JOIN (SELECT *, REGEXP_SUBSTR(prncode, '^[A-Z]+') as code 
      FROM TableB) b ON a.code = b.code
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code with a join. You can use any join based on your requirement.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB 
ON TableA.Code = 
left( TableB.pnrcode, length(TableB.pnrcode) - length( reverse( concat(TableB.pnrcode, "1") ) + 0 ) + 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` to remove `code` from `pnrcode`.
If what is left is a `number > 0` (MySql does implicit conversion) then join on that:

```
select *
from tablea a left join tableb b
on replace(b.pnrcode, a.code, '') > 0
```

I assume that all `pnrcode`s have numeric part other than `0`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aC6NcaL946UqS3aGSCmNBL/1).
Results:

```
| code | pnrcode |
| ---- | ------- |
| A    | A001    |
| AB   | AB001   |
| B    | B001    |
| BB   |         |
```

Comment: Based on TableA i need to compare and select based on match case

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

with res as
     (SELECT dbo.AlphaOnly(a.Prccode) as Prccode1,* from TableA a)
      SELECT * from res join Tableb b on b.Code=res.prccode1
      go

Comment: What is this? If it is an example of what you have tried then add it to your question instead.